# Special chars separate words for "suggestions"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im new to VS Code and i would like to know if its possible to fix the problem i met.
It seems like special chars are separating words for "suggestions" and its really annoying.

[image]

Here u can see that it suggests me only the first part before `-` character.
Is it possible to ignore special chars for "suggestions"?

Comment: Can you provide what programming language is in use?

Comment: its generally for html since there is a lot of css classes contains '-' in name